# Scroll doesn't work after gesture actions in mobile browsers

Tags: javascript, ios, scroll, multi-touch, mobile-browser

I have a large scrollable page. Scroll works when I swipe the content by fingers up and down. So it works like it must work.

But if I perform several gesture (multi-touch) actions, then scroll stops to work. I move fingers up and down, but it no longer move.

Often the single gesture action is not enough, I must perform several gestures to crash the scroll. But I can't understand, what is wrong.

Comment: It is the device/browser that handles the multi-touch and gestures. You may have to log a bug report with the SDK provider.

Comment: Are these gesture handled by you? that is do you have listeners on touchstart touchend and so on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. Yes, that was pretty stupid, but maybe my experience could help if someone will face with something similar.

My page contained some elements that had event listeners on touchstart, touchmove and touchend. That listeners included `event.preventDefault()` under some conditions and no `event.stopPropagation()`. After some gestures conditions became `true` and event prevention starts to block the scroll.

In my case I didn't need these event handlers anymore, that's why I just removed them completely. This solved the problem.

In other similar cases adding `event.stopPropagation()` could solve the problem. Also it is necessary to check conditions (if any) that calls `event.preventDefault()`.